# how to keep program running after .mainloop()?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a program which displays images using tkinter. The code I've written so far displays the image perfectly, however the program does not continue until the tkinter window is closed. I was wondering if there was any function instead of .mainloop() to keep the program running alongside the tkinter window? Any help much appreciated

> 

```
window = Tk()                                                         
canvas1 = Canvas(window,height=600,width=600)                         
file = PhotoImage(file = 'GoogleDrive.png')                                          
image = canvas1.create_image(300, 300, anchor = CENTER, image = file) 
canvas1.pack()
canvas1.mainloop()

print ('\nA: Google Drive')
time.sleep(1)
print ('B: Google Slides')
time.sleep(1)
print ('C: Google Photos')
```

Comment: use `tkinter.after()` instead of `sleep()`

Comment: Your program _does_ keep running after `mainloop`. It's just that is an infinite loop. If this is not what you're asking then this question is a duplicate of [How do you run your own code alongside tkinter's event loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459083/how-do-you-run-your-own-code-alongside-tkinters-event-loop).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you run your own code alongside Tkinter's event loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459083/how-do-you-run-your-own-code-alongside-tkinters-event-loop)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `mainloop` needs to be the last logical line of code. The mainloop should also be called on the `Tk` object, in your case `window`.

In order for your code to run, you either need to move the `print` and `sleep` statements before the `mainloop`, or move them to a function and instead call that function, before the mainloop.

It is also worth noting that in Tkinter, you can use `after` for timings instead of `sleep`.

Comment: Thank you, really helped :)

Answer (score 3):

Tkinter is event driven.  This means that there must be an action (from the script or user) given to tkinter to change things.

The `mainloop()` function executes the window so there is no alternative to it.  Fortunately there are solutions:

If you want to perform actions alongside tkinter window(s) you have two options:

You can perform them all before `mainloop()` is called.

Or make them execute when a user performs an action in form of a button ect.

Or you can run functions in the background with [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) or [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html).

If you go for this option I would suggest threading because:

- It's easy to use
- You can communicate between different parts of the script.  You can struggle to do this in multithreading

However this depends entirely on the specific task.

---

In the example code you have given your best option is to call it before `mainloop()` is executed.  For example:

```
window = Tk()                                                         
canvas1 = Canvas(window,height=600,width=600)                         
file = PhotoImage(file = 'GoogleDrive.png')                                          

image = canvas1.create_image(300, 300, anchor = CENTER, image = file) 
canvas1.pack()
print ('\nA: Google Drive') 
time.sleep(1)
print ('B: Google Slides')
time.sleep(1)
print ('C: Google Photos')
canvas1.mainloop()
```

Although you could put it anywhere before `mainloop()`.

Comment: Thanks :) helped a lot

Comment: @KyleH  No problem.  Happy to help.